# Reading csv file from S3 and converting it to xlsx using Python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, xlsx

I have a big csv file in S3 and i cam concatenating it with another csv file in S3. I am using pandas dataframe in python to do this in AWS lambda. I also have to save the concatenated data frame to xlsx format in S3 using the same lambda. Is there a way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import boto3

df1 =pd.read_csv("file1.csv",header=None,lineterminator='\n',sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, encoding='ISO-8859-1') # file is in s3.

df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv",sep='\t',header=None)

df3 = pd.concat([df2,df1])
```

I want to save the result in df3 object as excel file in s3.

Note: I have already tried df.to_excel(). But since i need to save it directly to s3 it is not working.

Comment: have you tried `df.to_excel` ?

Comment: yeah, df.to_excel takes an ExcelWriter object which needs a path for a file. I had put the path to file stored in s3 and that did not work. So i am not sure if that is the write way to go

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) says it accepts a File path or existing ExcelWriter. why would it work with an s3 object key?

Comment: i want to save it directly to s3. Convert the csv and write it directly to s3 to save processing time. The file is going to be atleast 500MB

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by following code :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: i want to save it directly to s3, so instead of 'test.xlsx' should i give location to a S3 file? My requirement is to save it directly to s3.

Answer (score 0):

try`df3.to_excel('filename.xlsx')`